# how to find source files of node when using "node --inspect-brk index.js"

Tags: node.js, node-inspector

I am now trying to debug one node application, and using 'node --inspect-brk index.js', I can see all those node internal source files now (just as following snapshot).

I run into one issue and want to do some hack to those files in my macbook, while I fail to find them.

Is it possible to find those files in my local directories and modify some of them?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change those files. Those are internal node source files.

Comment: thanks, seems I can only recompile the node source code locally after hacking those files to achieve what I want.